Square of first Stiefel-Whitney class is zero implies it comes from reduction of an integral class
I heard the following proposition from my friend, but we don't know how to prove it.

If $M$ is a manifold and $w_1\in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is the first Stiefel-Whitney class corresponding to some bundle, then $w_1$ is the reduction of an integral class if and only if $w_1\cup w_1=0$.

I can only prove that $w_1^2=0$ is equivalent to $w_1$ being the reduction of a $\mathbb{Z}_4$-coefficients class.
This is because
$$w_1 \cup w_1 = Sq^1(w_1)=\beta(w_1),$$
where $Sq^1$ is the first Steenrod square and $\beta$ is the Bockstein homomorphism associated with the short exact sequence of coefficient groups $0\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to\mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to0$.

Note that every
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\iso}{\cong}$
class in
$H^1(M; \Z_2)$ is the 1st Stiefel-Whitney class of some line bundle, so we might as well forget about $w_1$ and talk about general cohomology classes.
It's true that if $a \in H^1(M; \Z_2)$ is the mod $2$ reduction of an integral class, then $a^2 = 0$. However, the converse is false. Here is a counterexample:
Example. Let $M$ be a Lens space with $\pi_1 M \iso \Z_4$. The homology of $M$ is computed in Example 2.43 of Hatcher. In particular, we have
$H_1(M ; \Z) \iso \Z_4$ and $H_2(M; \Z) = 0$. From the universal coefficients theorem, we then get the following cohomology groups:
\begin{align*}
H^1(M; \Z) &= 0\\
H^1(M; \Z_2) &\iso \Z_2 \\
H^2(M; \Z_2) &\iso \Z_2 \\
H^2(M; \Z_4) &\iso \Z_4
\end{align*}
Let $a \in H^1(M; \Z_2)$ be the non-zero class. By the above, $a$ is not the mod $2$ reduction of an integral class. On the other hand, I claim that $a^2 = 0$. As observed in the OP, this is equivalent to showing that $\beta (a) = 0$, where $\beta$ is the Bockstein morphism associated to the exact sequence $0 \to \Z_2 \to \Z_4 \to \Z_2 \to 0$. To show this, consider the associated long exact sequence in cohomology:
$$
\underbrace{H^1(M; \Z_2)}_{\Z_2} \xrightarrow{\beta} 
\underbrace{H^2(M; \Z_2)}_{\Z_2}
\xrightarrow{f}
\underbrace{H^2(M; \Z_4)}_{\Z_4}
 \xrightarrow{g}
\underbrace{H^2(M; \Z_2)}_{\Z_2}
$$
If we had $\beta(a) \neq 0$, then $\beta$ would be surjective.
But then we would have $f= 0$, hence $g$ would be injective, a contradiction.

As an addendum here: From the relationship that $Sq^{1} = \rho \circ \hat{\beta}$, where $\rho$ is reduction mod $2$ and $\hat{\beta}$ is the Bockstein for $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$, you can show that the OP's proposition is true provided that $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ has no $4$-torsion.
